# C++ Calculate total rainfall from a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

I have a dataset containing information about the total rainfall in each month from a range of years. I need to calculate the total rainfall for all the years using the months in each year, and output the corresponding year. The dataset has been put into a vector of a class object using getters, allowing me to pull information such as the year and month with the highest temperature, for instance.

```
~snip
```

I'm not too sure as to how to I should go on about it. Do I add up the rainfall for each year using a loop 12 times? Or is there a better way to go on about it? And before I get slated, I did try a bunch of things but it didn't work, hence why I'm asking here.

I've managed to print the highest rainfall for the month from the dataset as follows:

```
~snip
```

Comment: Instead of a simple `std::vector` you could use a `std::map<int,std::vector<YourDataStruct> >` which keeps the year as the key value.

Comment: Is there any concern on looping 12 times? What did you try but didn't work?

Comment: Honestly, there are a few ways to do this depending on your performance requirements. If this is for a class, just do the bloody for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::map (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).  You only need one loop.

The following is an example iterating over dataVector.

```
std::map<int,double> result;

for( std::vector<YourDataStruct>::iterator it = dataVector.begin(); it != dataVector.end(); ++it ) {

    if(result.count(it->getYear()) == 0)
        result[it->getYear()] = it->getRain();
    else
        result[it->getYear()] += it->getRain();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in a vector and data is stored as in file, year by year, you can provide a predicate to search in vector by year (use lambda in C++11 or write unary predicate as a functor object):

```
double averageRainfall( std::vector<Rain>& year) {
    /* first record for a given year */
    std::vector<Rain>::iterator b = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), year,
                               []( const Rain& r){ return ( r.year == year);});
    /* 1 past last record for a given year */
    std::vector<Rain>::iterator e = std::upper_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), year,
                        []( const Rain& r){ return ( r.year == year);}));
    /* calculate the sum */
    double sum = std::accumulate( b, e , 0.0);
    /* and average */
    double mean = sum / std::distance( b, e);
    return mean;
}
```

[std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

---

You should consider using some kind of *multi-key map*, i.e. `std::multimap< int, std::vector<Rain> >` as a data structure to hold your records. It will be easier to process information.

[std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure for your records.

Read the records from the file into `std::vector`.

Create an `std::map` for each field you want to index (sort) by.  The key field will be the data type of the column in your table.  Something like this:

```
std::map<double, unsigned int> temperature_index;
```

The value field, unsigned int in the above example, will be the index of the element in the vector.

By having multiple index tables, you can reference your vector in any order you want without sorting the vector.  You can even have different ordering schemes.